# Emoji IOS keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter

For showing emojies I am using `emoji_picker` package, but still emojies arn't IOS emojies. I want use IOS emojies. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Apple protected their emojis and fonts from being used on Android, and anywhere else for that matter, so I don't think there's any legal way to use them in your app. Even Whatsapp had to stop using them.

[This](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/8/16992830/apple-emoji-crackdown-cross-platform-apps-slack-whatsapp) article explains it.